# iOS 6 supportedInterfaceOrientations issue

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, orientation

In my view controller, I implement two methods for controlling interface orientation:

```
- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    return YES;
}
```

In the `supportedInterfaceOrientations` method, I return `UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait` but at that time I realized that the `shouldAutorotate` method is not being called.

But I change to `return UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait` in the `supportedInterfaceOrientations` method. The `shouldAutorotate` method is being called, but there is an error that mentions in following:

> `UIApplicationInvalidInterfaceOrientation`, reason: 'Supported orientations has no common orientation with the application, and shouldAutorotate is returning YES'

By the way, I select all orientations in the supported interface orientations.

EDITED

i use viewController and embed with navigationController.
here is AppDelegate.h

```
@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate,UINavigationControllerDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;

@property (readonly, strong, nonatomic) NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext;
@property (readonly, strong, nonatomic) NSManagedObjectModel *managedObjectModel;
@property (readonly, strong, nonatomic) NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *persistentStoreCoordinator;
@property (readonly, strong, nonatomic) UINavigationController *navController;
- (void)saveContext;
- (NSURL *)applicationDocumentsDirectory;
@end
```

in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method under AppDelegate.m

```
      navController = (UINavigationController *)self.window.rootViewController;
                IPad_HomeViewController *rootVC=(IPad_HomeViewController *)navController.topViewController;
                rootVC.managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;
return YES;
```

in my IPad_HomeViewController,

```
@interface IPad_HomeViewController : UIViewController <UINavigationControllerDelegate>
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext;
@end
```

Comment: I don't think code is need just to change its orientation, you do this in the menu Targets->Summary-> Supported Device Orientations and change as following.

Comment: @Programmer... You have to do it in code if a particular screen supports different orientations from the broader app.

Comment: check my answer for ios 6 and also pre ios 6 sample codes. hope it helps.

Comment: Your app delegate looks fine. Try setting autorotate to yes in all of the view controllers and then set the rotation desired. See if that works. I actually built a demo single view project and tested the code. It works fine.

Comment: I return Yes in shouldAutorotate method and set UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait in supportedInterfaceOrientations method. but shouldAutorotate is not being called and error still remains. btw i also have shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation method for ios5. if possible, can you send ur sample code to me? Thanks really.

Answer (score 2):

```
- (BOOL) shouldAutorotate {
    return YES;
}

// for landscape
- (NSInteger) supportedInterfaceOrientations {
    return (1 << UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft) | 
           (1 << UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight);
}
```

As noted above, check out the mask values for specific orientations : UIInterfaceOrientationMask values.[UIInterfaceOrientationMask](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/supportedInterfaceOrientations)

Answer (score 1):

Two points:

1. Your error message makes complete sense because it makes no sense to use `UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait` as a return value from `supportedInterfaceOrientations`, which is returning a bit mask. Use one of the [`UIInterfaceOrientationMask`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/c/tdef/UIInterfaceOrientationMask) values.
2. You seem to be concerned that if you use the proper `UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait`, that iOS doesn't appear to call `shouldAutorotate`. It may only call `shouldAutorotate` if, having considered the physical device's physical orientation and the app's current orientation against the `supportedInterfaceOrientations` that a rotation might be needed. Why should it check `shouldAutorotate` if it concludes that the device is in an acceptable orientation already?

See [supportedInterfaceOrientations](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/supportedInterfaceOrientations) and [Handling View Rotations](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006926-CH3-SW57) for more information.

Comment: actually i face some issue. i used storyboard and created a lot of viewcontrollers. i want viewController A to portrait mode even if user rotate the ipad device, it is still in portrait mode. Moreover, i want landscape (left) mode for my viewControllerB. when user shift to viewController A to viewController B, viewControllerB automatically change to Landscape(Left) mode and lock with landscape orientation even if user change to portrait mode.

Answer (score 1):

I know this sounds pretty elementary, but I was wracking my brain to figure out orientation issues while testing on my iPhone - I had the physical auto lock mode in Portrait mode - so nothing I changed programmatically mattered - thought this should be troubleshooting step number 1!

Answer (score 0):

In order to change the orientation setting, select menu Targets->Summary-> Supported Device Orientations and change as following.

If the buttons for the orientation are dark then that means you have selected it as one of the orientation. 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

rather than using an integer to declare the orientation why don't you use a bool and plug in a if statement in there to detect whatever orientation you want. here is a example code that i hope would help you:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
if (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait) {
    return YES;
}
if (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown) {
    return YES;
}
return NO;
}
```

you can add all of the orientations in the if statement and it should work just fine. adrian

Edit:

and if you want to have an option for ios 6 the below code should work just fine for you.

```
- (BOOL) shouldAutorotate
{
return YES;
 }

-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeRight | UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeLeft   | UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait | UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortraitUpsideDown;
}
```

you can change just about all the supported orientations with this in ios 6. happy coding

EDIT 1:

to rotate only certain `viewcontrollers` in a certain way, just use the ios 6 code that i posted above in all `viewcontrollers`. here are the steps:

1. in the project level where all four `internfaceorientations` are located, go ahean and turn everything off so app would go to default.
2. implement the ios 6 code that i supplied in all `viewcontrollers`.
3. rather than yes declare no in `shouldautorotate` method.
4. in the second method, plug in any type of orientation you want.

this should do the trick for you. happy coding

Comment: thanks rob. good point. i added some more code for ios 6 to my answer. thanks again.

Comment: actually i face some issue. i used storyboard and created a lot of viewcontrollers. i want viewController A to portrait mode even if user rotate the ipad device, it is still in portrait mode. Moreover, i want landscape (left) mode for my viewControllerB. when user shift to viewController A to viewController B, viewControllerB automatically change to Landscape(Left) mode and lock with landscape orientation even if user change to portrait mode.

Comment: that is pretty easy dartfrog. check the edit of my answer please.

Comment: Hi Amp, i did it according to your way. i off every orientation in prj level. but only detect supportedInterfaceOrientations method and still shouldAutorotate is not being called. may be AppDelegate i setup wrongly. i edited my question.

Comment: I commented on your edit. Was your problem resolved or still persisting?