# iPad App Portrait Only?

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad, uitabbarcontroller, autorotate

My app is entirely designed for IOS6.  I use an xib for the iPhone and another one for the iPad.  My AppDelegate sets up a TabBarController, though there is no class for the TabBarController itself.  The TabBarController has two tab items, 1 a NavigationController, and 1 a View Controller, each of which has its own class.  I would like the iPad to be able to run in just Portrait mode, upside down, and normal.  On the summary tab of Target in Xcode, I have supported interface orientations set to Portrait and Portrait Upside Down.

My understanding with iOS 6 is that you only need to put

```
- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
```

in the highest parent controller of a class, and set which Masks you would like it and all the child containers to work with. So, in the Root View Controller of the Navigation Controller I put:

```
- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait|UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortraitUpsideDown;
}
```

And in each of the child classes, I put:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate{

    if( UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad )
    {

        return YES;

    }
    else
    {
        return NO;
    }


}
```

I then put the same two methods in the 2nd Tab which was just a View Controller Class.

I installed the app on my iPad, and it worked fine in portrait mode, but did not rotate when I turned it upside down.  I exited the app and turned the iPad upside down, but when I started the app again, it still stayed in the same spot.  So, I killed the app completely, and started it from the beginning upside down.  The splash screen was upside down, but when the screen disappeared, the app was still only showing in portrait mode, making the display upside down.

What am I missing?

Comment: Check the link in my answer for the necessary code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

click on appName select Target and just select the orientations which you want to support. thanks

[image]

Comment: If you read the question, you would see where I said "On the summary tab of Target in Xcode, I have supported interface orientations set to Portrait and Portrait Upside Down."

Comment: Yes, but that's _all_ you have to do. Don't implement any other rotation code.

Comment: I have set that to portrait only, but my Universal app in iOS 8 still autorotates.

Comment: please check your project info.plist options focus on "Supported interface orientations" @coolcool1994

Comment: modifying "Supported interface orientations" in info.plist works! I have another question: after you only allow Portrait (home button down), is there a way you make one, and only one, view controller within root navigation controller to have the Landscape orientations? If I want this would I have to include landscape object under "Supported interface orientations" in info.plist?

Comment: the answer is no, you can rotate viewController if your allow only portrait orientation. in your case your need to allow portrait and landscape both orientation and handle them with their methods.

Answer (score 0):

The code above is great for pre iOS 6. For iOS 6 you have to use the mask orientation. If you want all of the views in iPad to rotate or just some you have the choice of using the above answer. If you want to hard code it the check my answer in the following link for a detailed code for autorotation of all masks or just rotate one view and let the others don't rotate. Any how here is the link
[iOS 6 supportedInterfaceOrientations issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13902469/ios-6-supportedinterfaceorientations-issue/13902779#13902779)

The above answer is providing you with the right solution as well but if you want to learn how to code it check my answer in the link above. Happy coding.

Comment: So you're saying that -(BOOL) shouldAutorotate is not needed?

Comment: I only use it when I want to turn the rotation off and set a certain view to portrait and the rest to another rotation. For example view 1 portrait, view 2 landscape and all other views something else. Otherwise I just set the rotation to yes and it works just fine on iPad and iPhone the same.

Answer (score 0):

Is the Rotation Lock enabled or not ? (If you are new to iOS, double tap the home button, and slide to the right: it's the little metal-styled button in shape of an arrow).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run your application to run on portrait mode only than,
1. Select Your Target.
2. In General -> Development Info -> Device Orientation Uncheck all other orientation.Portrait mode only should be checked.Than run your project.